# Will file() affect the performance for files approximately 2 MB in size?

Tags: php

I have only one option to grab that data from this text file, so I cannot use database to store that. The file from which the function grab data is being re-created everyday at 00:00, so it's not a problem that it will get really big. Maximum 2 MB of size and with maximum of 6,000 - 7,000 lines at the end of the day. **My concern is that it grabs data and display it on webpage where it can be accessed a lot of times (`approximately up to 10,000 per day or less`) -- will it somehow really overload the server using `file()` or for this small file it should be fine?** Please let me know. Thanks for taking the time to read my question and possibly answer.

**Example lines from the .txt file:**

```
1,42,16, 201,stackoverflow_user, 1, 6762160, 39799, 9817242, 6762160, 39884, 10010545,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1351147, 1165, 483259, 1351147, 1115, 241630, 0 
1,46,27, 201,[stackoverflow_user | stackoverflow_userother], 1, 4078465, 286991, 1594830, 4078465, 287036, 1643156,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1357147, 1115, 241630, 1357147, 1065, 120815, 0
```

**My function:**

```
# read a file into an array
$lines = file('C:/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

# flip our array over so the last lines of the file are first.
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
$n = 1;
$wanted = 21; # or however many lines you want.
$content = '';

foreach ($lines as $l) {
   # treat the data as comma-separated values
   $arr = explode(",", $l);
   # if col 5 has multiple values, take the first one
   if (preg_match("/\[(.+?) \|/", $arr[4], $matches)) {
       $arr[4] = $matches[1];
   }
   # is arr[4] the same as arr[12]?
   if ($arr[4] !== $arr[12]) {
       # these two are not equal, so use these values
       $data = array('rank-pos' => $n++, 'rank-name' => $arr[4], 'rank-dmuser' => $arr[12]);
       $content .= Template::Load('rankinguserdm-' . ($n % 2 == 1 ? 2 : 1), $data);
   }
   # have we got enough data?
   if ($n === $wanted) {
       break;
   }
}

        $this->content = Template::Load('user_rankingsdm', array('rankings' => $content));
    }
```

Comment: If the file only changes once a day, I would cache the page on the first load and only serve the cached version afterwards

Comment: No, it updates during the day (lines are added one by one during the whole day), so its required to show up-to-date new info from the lines. So my main concern is if the page is loaded a bit more during the day, can these small files in size still overload the server? It has 16 GB of RAM running on Windows Server 2008 with nginx installed.

Comment: It's hard to give a yes/no answer without knowing more details. What else is going on on this server, how frequently is the script run etc. etc. PHP isn't the fastest language either. Keeping the file on RAM might speed it up a bit. My advice: Use this program and monitor your server's load for a while.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The server will be mostly loaded with additional applications and this script for grabbing data will be accessed frequently too. So, my main concern is if this isn't really bad way of doing it ? I dont think it will load the server a lot but just scared if that's really a good way to do what I want even when it works? Please let me know about it.

Comment: Files over 2GB in size can cause problems with PHP's internal filepointer

Comment: So, i should be on the safe side even if the script to grab data from this text file is accessed more often?

Comment: Please let me know. It will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the context. If you don't expect *that big* amount of traffic, then it should be OK. Otherwise, find a way to store it *somewhere*. Database, RAM, nuclear shelters -  anything will do the job, just do not read it from the file system every time.

I once had a similar issue with having to read text logfiles (each about 10 MBs) from a remote server a few times per second. I thought that since there weren't *that* many users, I could just take the easy shortcut and get them each time directly from the remote server. Long story short, that easy shortcut backfired when it turned out that my server was effectively DoS-ing the remote.

I eventually had to store all the data on a MySQL database, while keeping track of each file's size and reading only from the end of the previous read cycle (in order to avoid duplicates). Each file could be requested from the remote not at most once per minute. Along with a few other tricks, the remote server was doing happily its job, and my server had fresh enough data for my needs.

tl;dr: decide depending on how much load do you expect, the amount of users and the hardware you got. If you suspect at some point you will have huge loads, make yourself a favor and don't do it  on-the-fly

Cheers

Comment: I totally understand and thanks for posting this detailed explanation. However, I expect around 10,000 page access at maximum per day, do you believe for a 2 MB file with at maximum of 7,000 lines, it will be a problem? The server is hosted with Limestone Networks and it's a dedicated Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 16 GB of ram running with nginx installed. There will be additional services running on it but I really dont believe it will overload, let me know your opinion based on what I've said in this comment. Thank you once again!

Comment: Again, it will depend on the quantity of these services and the resources they take, but otherwise I think you'll be fine for now. 10 thousand requests per day is about 1 request / 8.4 seconds, which isn't something to worry about. If you start to approach 1 request / 1 or 2 seconds though, I think it will start to struggle.

Answer (score 0):

You could poll the file at intervals, say every 10 minutes. First time in the day read the data in, then cache both that data, and also save the length of the file found in that read. Each subsequent poll you only read from the where the last read got to, up to the new end of file, and add that new piece of data to the cache. Just carry on doing that through the day. Each time you are only reading the last few lines to be added, so you could probably poll it as fast as you like within reason if necessary to always be sure you got the latest line (but maybe the last line or two are not vital to show immediately, meaning you can poll less often to save load).

You don't say how many times the web page is likely to be accessed - if only twice a day then your file server won't be overloaded, but if a million times a day, yes it will almost certainly! But in a sense the actual number of accesses in normal life is irrelevant, if there could come a time when a run on the web page might occur. For instance, suppose it's a company's site, and suppose the shares suddenly shoot up one day, and half the world and his dog want to look at the site. The web host might cope, if it's a reliable one, but your file server might have problems.

Comment: Let's say approximately 10,000 times a day to be accessed and requesting data from this text file. Do you believe this can be a concern when we have small files like 2 MB and maximum of 7,000 lines?